# Term insurance in USA

Tags: united-states, life-insurance

Can I buy term insurance in the USA if I am not physically present in the USA? I found that I am asked for the zip code whenever I fill out my details to buy insurance.

Comment: What connection do you have to the United States?

Comment: I have US financial assets that I bought while I was there. I derive income from them, and they are subject to an estate tax of 40% which I want to cover with term insurance.

Comment: Yes you can and this is a product and service recommendation.

Comment: @base64 How? Everybody asks for zip code.

Answer (score 2):

While I understand it is possible to get a US based policy you will have some issues that need to be resolved:

- You will likely need a physical. Depending on where you are this will add to the time and cost of getting the policy, especially if you have to travel back to the United States for the physical.
- Term insurance as the name says covers you for X years. That means that over time the cost will go up. As you age the policy will cost more and more.
- The length of the term will be important. That dictates the time between physicals. As each term ends they will reevaluate your inseparability which will dictate your rate.
- When you hit your 50's and 60's and beyond the annual cost could sky rocket.
- This will not be a policy that you can buy over the internet. You will need to identify specific companies that offer plans for your situation.

Before trying to buy term insurance you should get a financial planner who specializes in international issues to look at how to minimize the tax hit when you die. They can determine how to protect the investment during the different stages of your life. It may turnout that a non-US policy is better, or some other insurance product. They should also be able to help you locate companies that will sell an insurance policy to somebody who isn't in the united states.

Comment: Can I not buy a policy without a physical by paying a higher rate? Or get a physical done where I am and send the reports there? Do you know what companies offer such policies? All I could get online was online offers for term insurance where they asked for the zip code. Non-US policies have exchange rate risk and bureaucratic risks associated with them. They would be my last option. All I am concerned about is the 40% estate tax. I have to pay tax on capital gains while I am alive. I don't want my estate to pay again 40% tax after I am gone. Yes, I will seek a financial planner.

Comment: This is the thing, nothing in the **law** says you can't buy. You just need to find the right broker/issuer that sells, and that becomes product and service recommendation. In fact, 26 U.S. Code § 2105 (a) says it is tax free upon death.

Comment: @base64 What do you mean by "that becomes the product and service recommendation"?

Comment: @user2371765 "Do you know what companies offer such policies" is off topic in this Stack Exchange. That was your goal.

Comment: @base64 I called up a website selling insurance. They told they will not sell insurance to non-residents.